# Show only 3 posts and sorting by price with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I have faced a problem I want to echo three `fullBookingURL` and `price` by for-each. My condition is showing 3 data which `price` is lowest in the array and then show that lowest `price` price

```
array (size=19)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3820]
      public 'agencyName' => string 'ZenHotels.com' (length=13)
      public 'fullBookingURL' => string 'http://example.com' (length=25)
      public 'price' => int 590
           public 'tax' => int 0
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3826]
      public 'agencyName' => string 'ZenHotels.com' (length=13)
      public 'fullBookingURL' => string 'http://example.com' (length=25)
      public 'price' => int 591
      public 'tax' => int 0
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[3835]
      public 'agencyName' => string 'Hotellook' (length=9)
      public 'fullBookingURL' => string 'http://example.com' (length=25)
      public 'price' => int 606
      public 'tax' => int 0
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[3838]
      public 'agencyName' => string 'ZenHotels.com' (length=13)
      public 'fullBookingURL' => string 'http://example.com' (length=25)
      public 'price' => int 712
      public 'tax' => int 0
  7 => 
    object(stdClass)[3841]
      public 'agencyName' => string 'ZenHotels.com' (length=13)
      public 'fullBookingURL' => string 'http://example.com' (length=25)
      public 'price' => int 713
      public 'tax' => int 0
```

**My code**

```
foreach($sval2->rooms as $bookingurl){
    echo $bookingurl->fullBookingURL; 
    echo $bookingurl->price;
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use foreach? You can first sort items in array using `uasort` with custom callback and then echo first 3 items of sorted array.

Comment: @kaduev13 no, its not mandatory?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @kerbholz show data 3 `price` which are lowest in the list and also show the `fullBookingURL`. Sorting with lowest price first.

Comment: Take a look at [array_slice()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Since your data is already sorted, you'd only need the first three items to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to sort items first using `uasort`, and then use `array_slice` to get first `n` elements (3 elements in your case).

```
<?php

// prepare some test data
$a = new \stdClass();
$a->url = 'first_url';
$a->price = 1;

$b = new \stdClass();
$b->url = 'second_url';
$b->price = 2;

$c = new \stdClass();
$c->url = 'third_url';
$c->price = 3;

$d = new \stdClass();
$d->url = 'third_url';
$d->price = 4;

$arr = [$d, $c, $b, $a];

// sorting elements
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) { return $a->price > $b->price; });

// printing first 3 elements
print_r(array_slice($arr, 0, 3));

// Array(
//     [0] => stdClass Object
//         (
//             [url] => first_url
//             [price] => 1
//         )

//     [1] => stdClass Object
//         (
//             [url] => second_url
//             [price] => 2
//         )

//     [2] => stdClass Object
//         (
//             [url] => third_url
//             [price] => 3
//         )
// )
```